# Checking RGB color value in C#?

Tags: c#, rgb

I am very new to C# and couldn't find any information on the color type online. Sorry if this is a poorly worded question.

I am trying to make an if statement that checks if the RGB value of a part in a color array is a certain color but I'm not exactly sure how to go about it. 
Basically what I want to do is this:

```
if(color[100, 100] = RGB Color 255, 0, 0)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 9):

That code in c# would be:

```
if (color[100, 100] == Color.FromARGB(255, 0, 0))
{
    //do something...
}
```

The `Color.FromARGB()` method also has an overload where the first parameter accepts an alpha opacity level from 0-255, but you probably won't need that.

The code above assumes that your `color[,]` array actually contains an array of colors, of course.

Comment: +1 This is correct. Note that even though the `Color` class provides some pre-defined values for the common colors (like `Color.Red`), you probably should not use these, as they will not necessarily produce the expected result using `==` or the `Equals` method. See the Remarks section of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e03x8ct2.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [System.Drawing.Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx)?